# Removing list members in scheme with remove*

Tags: list, scheme, racket

So I want to remove `#\space` from a list, lets say the list is `(#\a #\b #\space #\b #\space)` and I want to `(remove* (list space) (list #\a #\b))` all spaces.

So when I run,

```
(remove* (list #\space) (list #\a #\b #\space #\b #\space))
```

the print out is correct. i.e. `'(#\a #\b #\b)`

this is also true if I were to write:

```
(define somelist #\space)

(remove* (list somelist) (list #\a #\b #\space #\b #\space))
```

however if I create a list via:

```
(define somelist (string->list " "))
```

it fails.

I don't know what the difference is and why it doesn't work. Anyway in my program I need to get rid of the spaces that become part of the list via `string->list`. Any idea how to do this?

I'm using Racket.

Comment: `(somelist (string->list " "))` does not make sense. Did you mean: `(define somelist (string->list " "))` ?

Comment: That is what I meant and I edited accordingly thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrapping the char list in another list.

What you want is:

```
(remove* somelist (list #\a #\b #\space #\b #\space))
```

Comment: Thank you so much and for the very fast response! I am new to scheme. I'd upvote you if I had enough reputation points lol.